# How can I update Redux state array immutably using Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to learn Typescript by doing something simple like a Todo-List application. The problem is that I cannot update the Redux state array in a slice that I have created.(or more like I don't know how to)

Here is my main component `Todolist.tsx` :

```
import React, { FC, ChangeEvent, FormEvent, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { update } from '../todoSlice';
import { RootState } from '../todoStore';

const TodoList: FC = () => {

    // React state array for the todos
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState<string[]>([]);
    // Get the input from this state
    const [input, changeInput] = useState<string>('');

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    // Selecting the state of the todoSlice component
    const selector = useSelector((state: RootState) => { return state.todoCard })

    const handleChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
        event.preventDefault();
        changeInput(event.target.value);
    }
    
    const addTodos = (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>): void => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setTodos([...todos, input]);
        dispatch(update(todos));
        console.log("REACT: ", todos);
        console.log("REDUX: ", selector);
    }

    const removeTodos = (index: number): void => {
        let filteredArray = todos.filter((todo, todoIndex) => (
            todoIndex !== index
        ))
        setTodos(filteredArray);
    }

    return (
    <React.Fragment>
    <div className='bg-light d-inline-block text-center mt-4' style={{ padding: '10vh', marginLeft: '4vw' }}>
      <h1 className='mb-4'>Todo List</h1>
      <section className='text-wrap mb-4' style={{ overflowY: 'auto', height: '10rem' }}>
        {
          // Mapping thee todo-list items
          todos.map((todo, index) => (
            <React.Fragment key={index}>
              <div className='d-flex justify-content-between mb-3'>
                <li className='d-block'>{todo}</li>
                <button onClick={() => {removeTodos(index)}}>X</button>
              </div>
            </React.Fragment>
          ))
        }
      </section>
      <form onSubmit={addTodos}>
        <input type='text' name="input" className='p-1 rounded border-success' onChange={handleChange}></input>
        <button type="submit" className='ms-3 btn btn-success mb-1'>Enter</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    </React.Fragment>
    )
}

export default TodoList
```

and here is my slice component `todoSlice.ts` :

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export const todoSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'todo',
    initialState: {
        todoCard: [],
    },
    reducers: {
        update: (state, action) => {
            return {
                // Return a copy of the array and SHOULD update the state array here "immutably"
                ...state,
                todoCard: [
                    ...state.todoCard,
                    action.payload
                ]
            }
        }
    }
})

export const { update } = todoSlice.actions

export default todoSlice.reducer
```

I have tried many different ways from Google but none of their methods seem to work in my problem. Thank you for the responses in advance! :)

EDIT: I forgot to add the errors shown so here it is
[image: error image]

Comment: You didn't say what error you're getting or what incorrect behavior you're seeing in your application. Can you provide more detail about what isn't working?

Comment: Note also that when using Redux Toolkit, immutability happens automatically even when you write mutating code. So you can just write `state.todoCard.push(action.payload)`.

Comment: Please don't upload images of code or errors. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export const todoSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'todo',
    initialState: {
        todoCard: [],
    },
    reducers: { // <------- "Map Object" Notation
        update: (state, action) => {
```

By doing this you're using https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer with the "Map Object" Notation. This is what the redux-toolkit docs say about it:

> While this notation is a bit shorter, it works only in JavaScript, not
> TypeScript and has less integration with IDEs, so we recommend the
> "builder callback" notation in most cases.

So I'd recommend to rewrite this with https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer#usage-with-the-builder-callback-notation - you also don't need to worry about mutability then.

It also looks like there might be some type annotations missing. If `state.todoCard` is an array of strings, it should be annotated as such. There are lots of examples in the redux-toolkit docs to get better TS support. Check out https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript for example. Among other stuff, there is a version of `useSelector` that already knows how your redux state is typed, this helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need typings, your action is of type  **PayloadAction<string[]>**, try this

```
reducers: {
    update: (state, action: PayloadAction<string[]>) => { 
      ...
```

You should give a type to your initialState too

```
interface InitialState {
  todoCard: string[];  
}       

const init: InitialState  =  {
  todoCard: [],
}

export const todoSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'todo',
  initialState: init,
```